# Kabbalos pnei rabo (visiting one's rabbi) on Yom Tov

Tags: rabbis, zemanim, yom-tov, travel, kavod

That which it says in the Gemorah ([Rosh Hashana 16b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=16b&format=pdf)) that one has a obligation of "kabbalos pnei rabo" (to go see ones rebbe) on holidays - when is the obligation? Is there an obligation every day, or just once during the holiday? If it's only once is it specifically on Yom Tov itself or even on Chol HaMoed?

Certainly if the obligation is only one day, there would be a mitzvah every time he goes to see his rebbe. However, when is the actual obligation -- on yom tov, chol hamoed, or either one (or perhaps every day)?

(I will leave it to the learned olam here to fill in the sources that I have left out in the question as time does not permit at the moment to start looking. As well to make any changes in the question to enhance clarity.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obligation of visiting one's teacher on Yom Tov is brought in Gemora [Rosh Hashana 16b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=16b&format=pdf) and [Sukka 27b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=27b&format=pdf). Although codified by the Rambam ([Talmud Torah 5:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=3&perek=5&halocha=7&hilite=)) it does not appear in Tur or Shulchan Aruch (although the Magen Avraham does bring it on two occasions - [301:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14325&st=&pgnum=90) and [554:122](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14327&st=&pgnum=272)).

The Kaf Hachaim ([OC 529:34](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14424&st=&pgnum=146)) brings two contrasting views in the Achronim how this law applies nowadays. The Noda Beyehuda ([Mahadurah Tanina 94](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14662&st=&pgnum=62)) holds that since we no longer have a Beis Hamikdosh there is no obligation to visit one's teacher on Yom Tov (as it would not be correct to obligate one to visit his teacher more than visiting the Beis Hamikdosh) although he concludes that is a commendable practise to do so. However the Chida ([Simchas Haregel on Sukka 27b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19522&st=&pgnum=97)) maintains that the obligation is specifically nowadays, as it was instituted as a commemoration of the Aliya Laregel that we can longer observe.

Thus, certainly according to the Noda Beyehuda there is no specific obligation and if one wishes to go they may do say anytime during the Yom Tov. According to the Chida it would seem that the obligation is alike that of Aliya Laregel; the main time is the first day though he can make it up for the rest of Yom Tov ([Rambam Chagiga 1:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=9&hilchos=51&perek=1&halocha=7&hilite=)).

Comment: I don't understand the Noda Beyehuda: in what way are we not obligated to visit the Beis Hamikdosh?

Comment: @DoubleAA He says that the Torah only obligated us to do so when we can bring the Korbonos.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Noda BiYehuda was polemicising against hasidim when he asserted that there is no obligation to spend yontef with one's rebbe.

Comment: The Noda B'Yehuda I knew and didn't want to mention since I was asking really al pi the gemorah that says one is chayiv and not so much "l'maseh" rather according to the gemorah when would the chiyuv be. However after you point out what the Chida holds it makes it all the more pratical so thanks for that. I had ask around by Talmidei Chachamim in person and they had a similar consensus that it would be similar to that of the aliyah l'regel that the first day is the ikar and any day after that could also be done