# What is Kabbalos Pnei Rabo?

Tags: rabbis, yom-tov, travel, kavod, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

There is an obligation to visit ones Rebbe on holidays ([see here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20558/kabbalos-pnei-rabo) for details)

However the mitzvah or obligation that we know of, what does this mean exactly? Is it enough if I "see" my Rebbe even if he doesn't see me? What about if he sees me as well? Do I need to speak to him specifically? Say 'shalom', speak in learning? What's the definition of kabbalos pnei rabo?

Answer (score 3):

[Kaf HaChaim 419:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14422&st=&pgnum=340) indicates that this obligation is to learn from his Rabbi.

[Pnei Yehoshua Rosh Hashana 16b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19251&st=&pgnum=442) says that women are not included in this Mitzva as they are not obligated in learning Torah. That would indicate that the Pnei Yehoshua holds that the Mitzva of Kabalas Pnei Rabo is to learn Torah from the Rabbi.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't just preclude them from the definition because they don't have a _rav_?

Comment: @WAF: The Pnei Yehoshua does not say they are precluded because they do not have a Rav he says they are precluded since they are not Mechuyav in Talmud Torah.