# Visiting one’s rebbe virtually for a festival

Tags: halacha, technology, orach-chaim, maseches-rosh-hashana, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

According to this [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20640/33665) Jews  can make up their [obligation](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.16b.8) to visit their rebbe on Yom tov found in Masechet Rosh Hashanah by visiting during Chol  Hamoed of the holiday if they missed the opportunity during the first day of Yom Tov. However,  is it permitted  by  Halacha to fullfill this mitzvah through zoom or telephone?

Comment: Can you show were the obligation is from?

Comment: Just looking at the answer you based off of, acc to the chida, of course you can’t, the Noda Beyehida though, seems to be yes, since he just says it’s a commendable practice to visit.

Comment: Yes, but if it’s like Aliya Laregal, which when Mashiach comes, we won’t be able to do virtually, then of course you can’t visit your Rebbi’s virtually for this obligation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Chida, who holds it’s like Aliya Regalim, of course not since when Mashiach comes we definitely aren’t going to be able to be Aliya Regel virtually. According to the Noda Beyehuda though, you can, since he says it’s just a commendable practice to visit.

Comment: "According to the Chida" source? "when Mashiach comes we definitely aren’t going to be able to be Aliya Regel virtually" source/proof? "According to the Noda Beyehuda" source?

Comment: @Deuteronomy, the Chida and Noda beyehuda source are from the answer this question is based of off. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20640/33665

Comment: @Deuteronomy, the Aliya Regel is obvious, when you’re Aliyah Regel, you’re supposed to enjoy Yerusahlayim, you can’t do that virtually.

Comment: if you have citations you should edit to include the citations... if most of your work is piggybacking off of another answer, you should say so (both in terms of giving credit and in terms of the possibility that that person was incorrect). As for 'aliya la-regel in the future messianic era... nothing is "obvious" about it - we have no idea what transformations will take place within our legal system given the amount of technological change that has occurred.